# Not getting custom controls with HTML5 video tag on iphone and ipods even with phonegap (AllowInlineMediaPlayback)

Tags: android, iphone, ios, html, cordova

I am trying to build html5 video player with custom controls. While testing on iphone and ipods it popup native ios player with native controls. I want to show custom controls over there. After searching i found that with the help of webview i will able to show inline video player with custom controls on iphone and ipods.

After that i tried to make a ipa with phonegap v2.9 setting property AllowInlineMediaPlayback to true in config.xml and webkit-playsinline in video tag. But still i am not getting any success.

It will be helpful if anyone can share example of how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code [you already have](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (if any)?

Comment: This is what i have put in video tag:-
 <video id="my_video" width="480" height="300" preload="none" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline">

and in config xml i have put it like this :-
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />

I don't know where i am doing wrong.